# Check on/off of checkbox doesn't work anymore

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Since many years I have a website running ([direct link](http://geodata.grid.unep.ch/mod_table/table.php?selectedID=480&selectedDatasettype=1) to the table-page). Now, suddenly, I realise that the checkbox doesn't work anymore as one would expect (same for the "Completeness" button below): once the checkbox for "per capita"-calculation has been checked, it doesn't go off anymore. No idea why that is; really frustrating.

The page has two forms:

```
<form name="tableForm" action="">
  Per Capita: <input type='checkbox' name='per_capita' onchange='
    document.formGeneric.per_capita.value=document.tableForm.per_capita.value;
    document.formGeneric.action="table.php";
    document.formGeneric.submit()
  '>
</form>
```

and

```
<form method="post" name="formGeneric" action="">
  <input type='hidden' name='per_capita' value='on' />
</form>
```

Looks alright (although perhaps old-style writing) to me.

The "offing" off seems not to work at all. If I put a "alert(document.tableForm.per_capita.value)" in the onChange event, it still says "on".

I would very much appreciate any tip on what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Input "per_capita" in tableForm has no "value" attribute

Comment: `type="checkbox"` doesn't store its state in `value` attribute (present but unused), it uses `checked` attribute.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: That led me to the solution. Want to post it as an answer?

Comment: `document.tableForm.per_capita.value` can be `this.value`.

Comment: @luftikus143 little bit too _slim_ to be an answer! Feel free to self-answer your own question with more details and a code sample and I'l happily upvote it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to AdrianoRepetti's and Manurat's comments above, I realised that I had to work with two different "units": One is the information type="checkbox" is returning ("checked"); the other is how I store the information in a "hidden"-element in another form.

So, I changed the code to reflect this - it now parses the "checked" state of the checkbox over to the "value" part of the hidden element:

```
<form name="tableForm" action="">
  Per Capita: <input type='checkbox' name='per_capita' onchange='
    document.formGeneric.per_capita.value=document.tableForm.per_capita.checked;
    document.formGeneric.action="table.php";
    document.formGeneric.submit()
  '>
</form>


<form method="post" name="formGeneric" action="">
  <input type='hidden' name='per_capita' value='' />
</form>
```

Now, I use the PHP to check if the hidden parameter "per_capita" is "checked" or not.